# Will page table data be saved in the CPU cache?

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, tlb

The page table will be saved in memory and accessed during the page walk process after TLB miss. Will this portion of memory be treated as ordinary data and enter the traditional L1-D/L2/L3 cache?

If so[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44053150/will-page-table-be-put-in-cpu-cache)][[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256250/what-happens-after-a-l2-tlb-miss)], considering that these caches themselves require physical addresses for hit checking[[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77365951/is-l2-tlbs-on-the-critical-path-for-l1-cache-accesses?noredirect=1#comment136428504_77365951)], which in turn rely on page tables for address translation, has a circular dependency been generated?

If not, will this portion of memory be marked as "uncached"?

Comment: *which in turn rely on page tables for address translation,* - most ISAs [including x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46509152/why-in-x86-64-the-virtual-address-are-4-bits-shorter-than-physical-48-bits-vs) use physical addresses in their page tables for that reason.  Making them uncacheable wouldn't help with that; if you didn't know the physical address, you couldn't read them from DRAM either.

Comment: My answer on [VIPT Cache: Connection between TLB & Cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46480015) also mentions that page tables use physical addresses, and that page-walk fetches through the cache hierarchy.  (Apparently in P5, page-walk bypassed L1 cache, see Andy Glew's answer: [Are page table walks cached?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/67985))

Comment: [How does CPU make data request via TLBs and caches?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22572316) answers both parts of the question: TLB data is fetched via caches, and page tables use physical addresses.

Comment: @PeterCordes If page table entries can be cached like regular data, should cachelines corresponding to these page table data be shared when different threads belonging to the same process are running on multiple cores? Considering that these threads access the same page table. But in my experiment on AMD 9654 (with chiplet structure), I found that the proportion of `DC Fills from different CCX in same node` is very low, which means that the data is not shared among multiple L3 caches.

Comment: In the experiment, complete random access was performed on large memory regions, so TLB miss should occur frequently. I also tried different memory sizes, from 1GB to 512GB, and the results were the same.

Comment: Possibly AMD does something different from Intel, or perhaps page-walker loads bypass L3?  It might be worth asking a new question with details of your experiment.  Are you sure L3 misses will fill from a different CCX instead of DRAM even when the data is *clean*?  Dirty data of course has to be snooped by other cores, but clean data is optional.  Also, perhaps page-walker loads are often hitting in L1d or L2 cache, if somehow the PTEs aren't not always evicted by your random data accesses?  The upper levels of the page tables might get cached within the page walkers.